# Reconocer números iguales pero en diferentes posición Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo que poner en una lista que números son iguales pero tienen diferente posición ej: 12345 23451, el porblema es que mi codigo solo los mete a la lista si estan al revez ej: 12345 54321

````
resultados = open('resultados.txt','w')

for x in range(0,200):
    n=x
    for i in range(0,200):
        try:
            n+=1
            if(file[x] == file[n] or file[x] == file[n][::-1]):
                try:
                    if(file[x] == file[n]):
                        pass
                    else:           
                        resultados.write(f'{file[x]} = {file[n]}\n')
                        print(f'{file[x]} = {file[n]}')
                except:
                    pass
            else:
                pass
        except:
            pass```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución sin ocupar nada especial.

Los números a comparar los transformamos primero en listas de digitos. Si las listas son de distinto tamaños, no son el mismo número. Si el largo es el mismo, recorremos el primer valor, digito por digito. Por cada digito contamos las ocurrencias en el primer y segundo número. Si las cuentas difieren, los números son distintos.

La función `compara_iguales` retorna `True` si ambos números contienen los mismos digitos, y `False` en otro caso.

```
def compara_iguales(a, b):
    if len(a) == len(b):
        for digito in a:
            if a.count(digito) != b.count(digito):
                return False
        return True
    return False
```

#### Demo

```
a=list(input("Primer valor: "))
b=list(input("Segundo valor:"))
if compara_iguales(a, b):
    print("Iguales")
else:
    print("Distintos")
```

produce:

```
Primer valor: 12345
Segundo valor:34152
Iguales

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Set

En python puedes usar un tipo de dato `set` ([documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)) para comparar si los elementos que le componen son los mismos sin importar el orden.

```py
# %% inputs
n1='12345' 
n2='23451'
# %% convert to sets
set_n1=set(n1)
set_n2=set(n2)
# %% compare
set_n1==set_n2

# ===========
# Out>> True
```

Habría que agregar cambios si un número se repite y quieres que la cantidad sea la misma.

#### Sorted

También puedes ordenar ambas listas y compararlas, si el orden es el mismo cuando las ordenas de menor a mayor entonces tienen los mismos elementos en la misma cantidad pero en distinto orden.

```py
sorted(n2)==sorted(n1)

# ===========
# Out>> True
```

Comment: ¿Qué pasa al comparar 120 contra 112200?

Comment: @CandidMoe La primera opción con `Set()` da `True` ya que no tiene en cuenta la cantidad de veces que se repite un elemento, la segunda opción con `Sorted()` da `False` ya que sí considera la cantidad de veces.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un mapa para resolver fácilmente este problema. Un mapa es una estructura de datos asociativa que relaciona llaves con valores. Es importante notar que una llave mapea exclusivamente a un valor.

```
{
  'manzanas': 2,
  'peras': 5,
  'naranjas': 9
}
```

En el anterior ejemplo tendríamos un mapa en donde las llaves son el nombre de una fruta y el valor el número de unidades que tenemos de esa fruta.

En Python, la implementación de esta estructura de datos es un diccionario. En la documentación puedes encontrar más detalles del API: [Diccionario](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Ahora bien, la idea para resolver el problema sería recorrer uno de los números y crear un diccionario donde las llaves es el dígito encontrado y el valor es el número de veces que se repite ese dígito. Si tenemos el número `543523`, el diccionario resultante sería

```
{
  '5': 2,
  '4': 1,
  '3': 2,
  '2': 1
}
```

Luego, se crea otro diccionario para el segundo número con las mismas características. Por ejemplo, para `253453`, tendríamos el mismo diccionario.

Finalmente, solo queda comparar los diccionarios, para ello por cada llave en uno de los diccionarios se válida si esa llave existe en el otro diccionario y tiene el mismo valor.

El código sería algo así

```
"""
Dado dos numeros (x,y) devuelve True sii x == y cuando los digitos de 
ambos numeros se reordenan de menor a mayor
"""
def sonEquivalentes(x, y):
    x = str(x)
    y = str(y)

    # Contar las veces que se repiten los dígitos en x
    countX = {}
    for d in x:
        if d not in countX:
            countX[d] = 1
        else:
            countX[d] = countX[d] + 1

    # Contar las veces que se repiten los dígitos en y
    countY = {}
    for d in y:
        if d not in countY:
            countY[d] = 1
        else:
            countY[d] = countY[d] + 1
    
    # Si los diccionarios no tienen el mismo tamaño,
    # indudablemente los números no pueden ser equivalentes
    if len(countX) != len(countY):
        return False
    
    # Validar que los diccionarios sean iguales
    for k, v in countX.items():
        if k not in countY or countY[k] != v:
            return False

    return True

sonEquivalentes(543523, 253453) # Devuelve True
sonEquivalentes(123, 324) # Devuelve False
```

El comentario espero ayude a visualizar otra forma de resolver este problema que puede asimilarse un poco más a lo que tienes en este momento y resulte más fácil de escribir de manera pitónica.